# Geometry problem that I can't solve (polygons inscribed in a circle).

Tags: geometry, circles

I encountered this problem earlier and couldn't figure out how to solve it. I couldn't get all that far with the problem. The red marks were added by me, couldn't figure out anything other than those little details.

[image: diagram]

Can you guys help me with this? What am I missing?

Comment: Angle ADB is 90 degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: $ABCD$ is cyclic and so $\angle ADE + \angle DEA = \angle DCB$. But $\angle FEC$ is not determined by the given information.

Comment: Hint  Angle chasing gives FEB 90 deg, and FEBC  is cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: Angle ADB is 90 degrees, but I'm still not sure I can find EDB. Also, how is FEBC a cyclic quadrilateral? I thought all vertices need to touch the circle for it to be a cyclic quadrilateral?

Comment: Checked it out manually, FEB is indeed 90 degrees because ADB is 90 degrees. Will focus on proving. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CosaYa: My edited answer tells you how to prove it.

Comment: Made a mistake, it's angle EFC not FEC, sorry about that. Many thanks for the help!